# How do you sort this in underscore node js monogodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, underscore.js

I know I should have researched this but I am on a strict time schedule. How do make the following string:

```
[ { _id: { eventName: 'sometsdf', confirmed: false }, total: 1 },
  { _id: { eventName: 'somethon', confirmed: true }, total: 1 },
  { _id: { eventName: 'somethon', confirmed: false }, total: 1 } ]
```

into something like

```
[ { eventName: 'somethon, confirmed: 1 , unconfirmed: 1},
  { eventName: 'sometdsf, confirmed: 0 , unconfirmed: 1}, ]
```

I have used aggregate function from mongodb as following

```
obj.aggregate[{
$group: {
    _id: {eventName: "$eventObject.event_name", confirmed: "$confirmation"},
    total: {$sum: 1}
}
}]
```

It has been only 8 hours since I have learned about node js and this is an emergency since the back end developer left. Please help.

Comment: Do you always have atmost 2 entries for each event ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that underscore will help much over plain JS here. You just need to loop over the results and create the mapped object. If you use the `eventName` as the key then the results can group easily (thanks Ninetainedo).

```
let o = {}
docs.forEach(doc => {
  let eventName = doc._id.eventName;
  if (!o[eventName]) o[eventName] = { confirmed:0, unconfirmed: 0};
  (doc._id.confirmed)
    ? o[eventName].confirmed++
    : o[eventName].unconfirmed++
})
```

That ends up as an object rather than array, now `_.map` can help with the object -> array conversion.

```
let grouped = _.map(o, (val, key) => {
  val.eventName = key;
  return val; 
})
```

Comment: You are missing grouping, I think. The expected output has a length of 2 instead of 3.

Answer (score 1):

Brute force solution. Not elegant at all :)

```
let x =[ { _id: { eventName: 'sometsdf', confirmed: false }, total: 1 },
  { _id: { eventName: 'somethon', confirmed: true }, total: 1 },
  { _id: { eventName: 'somethon', confirmed: false }, total: 1 } ]


let y = x.reduce((result, current) => {

    if(!result[current._id.eventName]) {
        result[current._id.eventName] = {eventName: current._id.eventName, confirmed: 0, unconfirmed: 0}
    }

    if(current._id.confirmed) {
        result[current._id.eventName].confirmed += current.total
    } else {
        result[current._id.eventName].unconfirmed += current.total        
    }

    return result
},{})

console.log(Object.keys(y).map(k => y[k]))
```